# void vs. int in function in C

Tags: c

Just a beginner question. Is there a difference in using int() instead of void() in function? I know that you use void if there is no return value, but does using int instead of void mess up or or give a different output? Like:

```
{
  sample();
  return 0;
}
int sample()
{
  print("example");
}
```

instead of

```
{
  sample();
  return 0;
}
void sample()
{
  print("example");
}
```

edit: sorry for the dumb example guys.. im still a student

Comment: This really depends on the compiler and what it does. It could lead to *undefined behavior*. If you have a function which doesn't return a value, then don't declare it as such (declare the return type as `void`). Generally speaking, don't write code that doesn't make sense.

Comment: A decent compiler would give you warnings in the first example, and none in the second (assuming the first part is actually the body of `main`)

Comment: `void sample()` is correct and `int sample()` is not, that be the main difference.

Comment: Assuming there is no prototype for `sample` prior to the mystery function whose name you have omitted, a decent compiler will give you warnings in *both*, and error on the second. The first will warn you that `sample` is undeclared and assuming to return `int` (which it does, but the compiler doesn't know that yet), then warn you again because `sample` is missing a return. The second will warn you about the same first issue, but then error because `void sample()` no longer matches the implicit extern-assumption of `int sample()` made when compiling the prior code.

Answer (score 1):

1. you will get a compile error since the program expect you to return int but there is no "return int".
2. The function returned value kind of indicates the user what he should expect to get back from the function - for example:
   getNumber() -> user expect to get a number returned from this function and not void.

Comment: I missed your number 1, well spotted. Are you however sure that it is a compiler error? I think it is a warning.

Comment: @Yunnosch it isn't a compiler error; its a warning at-best, and can become an error if one wisely enables treat-all-warnings-as-errors in their builds (a sage piece of advice for *everyone*, new or old, to C).

Comment: @WhozCraig Good point. I will accept "should-be error", but think it should be explicit in the answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch I agree. Honestly without a proper [mcve] we don't even know if the OP has a proper prototype, a well-formed `main`, etc. so we're all kind of grasping here. Thus why my assessment is in a general-comment.

Comment: my mistake, as mentioned in another comment, there will be no compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a difference; several actually.

1. is using `int` for those two functions would be useless, confusing and suggesting a different use of the functions as shown. So only `void` is the kind way of not confusing everybody who has to read your code.
2. some compiler and code checkers, i.e. non-human readers of your code, might complain.
3. if using `int` does make sense (because the function have different code than shown), then the returned value gets ignored, which for those value-returning function variant is most likely a problem.
4. number 1 from Menis answer (which I missed), their number 2 seems to be my number 1

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference in using int() instead of void() in function? I know that you use void if there is no return value, but does using int instead of void mess up or or give a different output?

This is a good question. **The first thing you should do when you're wondering about such things is to try it out.** As a beginning programmer, you're going to have a *lot* of questions like that, and you'll learn a ton by just writing up a little example and experimenting with it.

I cleaned up your example so that it's a valid program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sample()
{
  printf("example");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  sample();
  return 0;
}
```

And then I compiled it:

```
gcc basicq.c
```

and I got the following output:

```
basicq.c:6:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
```

That's just a waning, not an error, so the program did compile and it runs. It works in this case because in your very simple code, you're not actually *using* the value that's supposed to be returned, so nothing goes wrong. But if you *did* actually try to use it, what would happen? Let's see... I'll change `main()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sample()
{
  printf("example");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = sample();
  printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

So now we're storing the value allegedly returned by `sample()` in variable `i` and printing it out. I get the same warning as above, and the output looks like this when I run it:

```
example0
```

The first part, "example" comes from `sample()`, and the `0` is from the `printf()` in `main()`. Why is it zero?

When a function is called, there's some space reserved on the stack for the return value. The `return` statement in the called function normally fills that space with whatever value the function wants to return. If the function fails to execute a `return` statement, then that space is still there and can still be read by the caller, but there's no telling what might be in it... it's *undefined*. And that's why you get a warning... the compiler is telling you "Hey, you said you were going to return a value but then you never did." But it'll still let you do it, because C gives you the power to do all sorts of things that aren't actually good ideas.

Let's try it the other way around and try to both return a value from a void function and get a value from a function that returns `void`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sample()
{
  printf("example");
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = sample();
  printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

This time, when we compile that code we get an error:

```
basicq.c:6:3: error: void function 'sample' should not return a value
      [-Wreturn-type]
  return 1;
  ^      ~
basicq.c:11:7: error: initializing 'int' with an expression of incompatible type
      'void'
  int i = sample();
      ^   ~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

That's because the `void` return type tells the compiler that nothing is returned, so there's no space reserved for the return value, and trying to write to or read from that space that doesn't exist doesn't make any sense... The compiler doesn't know how to generate that code, so it generates errors in both cases.